# How can I use the OpenCV library with Xojo?

Tags: xojo

I'm trying to get OpenCV to work with Xojo.

I've downloaded the [OpenCV folder](https://github.com/ldci/OpenCV-Xojo) for Xojo and followed the 'Getting Started' instructions [here](https://github.com/ldci/OpenCV-Xojo), where I copy the OpenCVX file (not folder as stated in the instructions) by right clicking on the project navigator -> Build Step -> Copy Files, but without success. I found other instructions [here](https://forum.xojo.com/t/getting-opencv-framework-installed-correctly/29892) where I copy the OSX folder into the project (Build Step -> Copy Files) and failed there too i.e. the compiler does not recognise the OpenCV methods.

I'm using MacOS Catalina and the free version of Xojo (1.2).

Has anybody had success in using OpenCV with Xojo? In which case please could you provide clear step-by-step instructions on how you got this to work?

Thank you in advance.